# Python - New to Python and I am trying to take a section of a list that is a string and make it a integer

Tags: python, for-loop

I'm trying to take this in stages, but I am stuck. Below is the task I am trying to complete, but I have run into a roadblock that I cannot seem to get over:

So far I have created the below for loops.

```
NBAList=[]

for line in NBAfile:
    textline =line.strip()
    items=textline.split('\t')
    NBAList.append(items)

for line in NBAList:
    print(line)

And get the below:

['1', 'Bulls', '894659', '21820', '104.3']
['2', 'Cavaliers', '843042', '20562', '100']
['3', 'Mavericks', '825901', '20143', '104.9']
['4', 'Raptors', '812863', '19825', '100.1']
['5', 'NY_Knicks', '812292', '19812', '100']
```

What I'm not sure of is how to get the last three numbers from strings to integers (the last one a float). I've tried several different ways but I keep getting errors. I think I can build off of what I have, but I'm just not doing it right. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

I am trying to get the basketball teams' total attendance, average attendance to be integers and capacity to be a float with 2 decimal points. I am also trying (and failing) to get the attendance totals to have the appropriate commas.

The end result I am looking for each line is -> ‘The overall attendance for Bulls was 894,659, with an average attendance of 21,820 and the capacity was 104.3%’

Comment: What did you try? What errors were you getting?

Comment: See https://note.nkmk.me/en/python-str-num-conversion/ for guidance.

Comment: I tried for i in NBAList:
    i=int(totatt)

print(i) 

but that only returned 894659, I was hoping for a list of the total attendance, then I was going to build off of that if I got what I expected.

I also tried the below and just got an error
for i in range(len(NBAList)):
    NBAList[i] = int(NBAList[totatt])
print(i)

I tried others, but have since deleted them so I can’t recall those attempts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you have the strings, convert the values you want to convert *before* appending anything to `NBAList`. For example,

```
NBAList = []

for line in NBAfile:
    textline =line.strip()
    items=textline.split('\t')
    items[0] = int(items[0])
    items[2:4] = map(int, items[2:4])
    item[4] = float(items[4])
    NBAList.append(items)
```

While the various calls to `int` and `float` are *expected* to succeed, based on the the assumed contents of the file, you may want to be prepared to catch  the `ValueError` that any of them could raise.

Comment: Thank you, I tried that and got exactly what I was looking for! I was on the total wrong track of thinking and don't think I would have thought of that, greatly appreciate it!!!